# Python crashing C# project

Tags: python, c#

I am working in unity and making a chatbot/virtual assistant. I have some python code which I want to execute. It works, however before it gets the output, the entire unity application hangs for like 5 seconds. It isn't efficient and is VERY noticeable.

I tried using IRON Python, but it failed. I know that starting a process isn't efficient, but is there some way I can optimize this?

Here's my c# code:

```
public static string RunPythonFile(PythonScript script, ExecuteMethod method, bool redirect)
{
    // Get Path
    string path = PYTHON_PATH;
    string filePath = script.ServerLocation;

    // Create ProccessStartInfo
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

    // Assign its path
    start.FileName = path;

    // Pass in arguments (if we have them)
    if (script.hasArguments) {
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", filePath, script.arguments);
    }
    else if (!script.hasArguments) {
        start.Arguments = filePath;
    }

    // Redirect stuff according to the input
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardError = redirect;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = redirect;

    // Check if we want to use the window(slower performance but more time)
    if (method == ExecuteMethod.withoutWindow)
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
    else
        start.CreateNoWindow = false;

    // Read text
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            // Return Result
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Python code:

```py
import sys
import Kalos_Train_Convo
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from Kalos_Training import Kalos_Training_Utility
from Kalos_Training import Kalos_Response

#Get Arguments
text = sys.argv[1]

modelPath = r"C:\Users\GAMING\Desktop\Kalos_Python\Test_Model2.h5"
wordPath = r"C:\Users\GAMING\Desktop\Kalos_Python\Test_Model2_words.pkl"
classPath = r"C:\Users\GAMING\Desktop\Kalos_Python\Test_Model2_classes.pkl"""

#Get Data
words = []
classes = []

#Create module
TrainingModule = Kalos_Training_Utility() 

#Get Model
words,classes,model = TrainingModule.LoadModel(modelPath,wordPath,classPath)

#Create Response object
response = Kalos_Response()

#Call Clean up method
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
iWords = response.clean_up(text,lemma)

#Create Bag of Words
intents = Kalos_Train_Convo.ConvoJSON()
iBag = response._bagofwords(iWords,words)

#Predict Class
iClasses = response._predict_class(classes,model,iBag)

#Get Response
iResponse = response._get_response(iClasses,intents)

#return that
print("\n")
print(iResponse)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: If you call this method with redirect = true, there is a chance for a deadlock. You are redirecting both standard output end error streams but you are reading only from output. If the buffer of the standard error stream get's full, your script will never end. If you get only a 5 sec delay, this will be the normal runtime of your script and you can't do nothing in `RunPythonFile` to speed it up.

Comment: So there's no way I can optimize it apart from removing the Redirect error part?

Comment: There is nothing time-consuming in your shown method. You could post your attempt with iron python and the problems you couldn't solve. I can't help you though with python...

Comment: @Steeeve I've Updated the question so you can see the python code